# Converting string date to timestamp in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-import, python-datetime

I am trying to convert string date to timestamp in Python as described in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python). When I run the code examples in the post, I encounter an error. For e.g.:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "01/12/2011"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 15, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:\Python34\calendar.py", line 9, in <module>
    calendar = wckCalendar.Calendar(root, command=echo)
NameError: name 'wckCalendar' is not defined
>>>
```

It looks like at runtime the code implicitly tries to `import calendar` and throws the error in the process. When I import calendar directly, I get the same error:

```
>>> import calendar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:\Python34\calendar.py", line 9, in <module>
    calendar = wckCalendar.Calendar(root, command=echo)
NameError: name 'wckCalendar' is not defined
>>>
```

I just want to be able to do the following:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "01/12/2011"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
```

Any ideas?

**Python 3.4.1 on Windows 7 32 bit***

Comment: Try `python -I` (isolation mode), read [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)

Comment: related to the title: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @J.F. Sebastian. I was caught in the `name shadowing trap`. I made the stupid mistake of naming one of my modules `calendar.py`. Once I removed this file, everything ran fine. I hope this post is not a waste and that someone may someday find it useful.