# Datetime 'has no attribute now'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to write a simple program to print the current date with Python 3.4. In the shell, I can import datetime, and use `now()` but when I write a script with a class it fails and gives this error:

```
"AttributeError: module object has no attribute now".
```

Can anyone help explain the problem? This is my code:

```
import datetime

class Date:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.writeToFile(filename)

    def date(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return now

    def writeToFile(self, filename):
        date = self.date()

        file = open(filename, 'w')
        file.write(date)
        for i in range(20):             # simply test for writting in file
            file.write(str(i)+'\t')
        file.close()
        return file

d = Date('datetime.txt')
```

Comment: Your file isn't called `datetime.py`, is it?

Comment: What a stupid mistake :( I am really sorry for wasting your time, everybody's time a didnt realise that, this could be a problem..Thanks one more :)

Comment: Don't worry, we've all fallen into this trap before :) Remember that you should also be mindful of not using variable names like `list` that shadow the built-in names. These mistakes can lead to very puzzling errors...

Comment: I think everyone gets caught by this once and then passes on the knowledge.

Comment: @MartinT_25: [you are not alone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25299371/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are importing the intended datetime module, and it is not being overridden by local files with same name. you can check it with:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.__file__)
```

and check the output if it is pointing to the correct directory you want.

Answer (score 15):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too and all I did was

```
Import datetime
from datetime import datetime

# then u can declare ur variable let's say something like
today = datetime.datetime.now()
#u can add what ever u want 
#the point is make sure u do the datetime.datetime.now()
print(today)
```